# Using PHP to change HTML permanently

Tags: php, html

I want my client to be able to log into their website, fill out a form and then have that webpage permanently have whatever they put into that form. Is there a way to use php to take whatever is submitted in that form and replace the html content with it? Im new to php, which functions could I use? And is it possible for php to permanently change anything on a site? Im not terribly concerned with security

Comment: Put the content in a database and read it. Question if far too broad though.

Comment: It's called CMS (Content Management System).  Wordpress, Joomla, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with wordpress and if you don't like it, then there are other content management systems out there. Google can help you find one too.

[Wordpress site](http://wordpress.org/)